# Access Application Changes not Working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access application that displays data from our database and does some operations on that data.  My problem is that I did not create this app, and when I try to add command buttons to a form, those buttons are not visible when deployed.  Any idea what might cause this?

To summarize: I add a button with VBA behind it, it works, but when I copy the App to another computer and run it, all of my changes are not visible.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure what you're running on the other computer is the updated application? Try putting a MsgBox() prompt somewhere in your updated version that pops up MsgBox("Yes, this is the new version."). If that doesn't pop up, then you're not actually running the file you think you are.

Comment: did David's suggestion get you any further?

Comment: I'll give that a try, but what can I do if its not the right file?  I've tries overwriting the old file, deleting it and then copying the new file over, and no dice.  Its almost like when I copy the new program the old one overwrites it.  Anyone know how that could happen?

Comment: There are two steps: 1. copy the file to a particular destination (which you seem to be confident is happening correctly) and 2. opening that file. There are a lot of reasons why you can end up doing step 2 wrong and be opening a file other than the one you assume you're opening, so you should be very sure about that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had an issue where I was using a short cut to launch the Access application. However, when I replaced the MDB, I deleted the original MDB. This only put it in the trash. The shortcut automatically updated to point at the file in the trash. It worked that way for weeks until I found it (under similar circumstances).

Try emptying your trash. And/Or double check the shortcut.

Comment: I always turn off the Distributed Link Tracking service which would prevent this from happening.

Comment: This sounds very similiar to my problem.  I'm a little afraid of turning off a service (I could do it temporarily), but how would I go about that?  Is it just in services.msc?  What else does that service do?

Comment: Ok, CodeSlave, you are completely my hero!!!  But why in hell is the .mdb taking itself OUT of the trash?  When I delete and then click the shortcut, the file reappears in the directory!  How is that possible?  I would expect the shortcut to give me that "I can't find the file" error...

Comment: You don't have to disable it, just change it from AUTOMATIC to MANUAL. Frankly, I've always found it really annoying, as it changes shortcuts I don't want changed.

Comment: @Mark - someone at MS thought it would be helpful; and I can see some arguments for that (b*tt-head decides to reorganise a directory tree not realising you have short cuts to files/folders in there). IIRC the shortcut is not necessarily pointing at the path to the file, but to may be pointing at the file handle. The path may change, but the file handle stays the same. My solution to be sure is to shift-Del the file (which doesn't send it to the trash) or empty the trash after I Del the file.